# Как устранить ошибку в методе save() фреймворка Codegniter?

Tags: php, mvc

Работаю с чужим кодом, фреймворк Codegniter практически не знаю, приходилось с другими фреймворками работать, но не суть.
Функционал реализовал(выпадающий список с выводом данных,который пользователь добавил на отдельной странице).
Но при сохранении получаю ошибку: Error Item not saved! 
Если убираю строку отвечающую за мой функционал (

```
'marketing_reason_for_leaving_id'  => $this->input->post('marketing_reason_for_leaving_id') ? $this->input->post('marketing_reason_for_leaving_id') : null
```

), то сохранение срабатывает. Не могу понять как это можно исправить.
    Вар дамп массива $vars : 
    array(29) { ["title"]=> string(2) "р" ["subscribed"]=> int(1) ["subscribed_active"]=> int(0) ["description"]=> string(2) "р" ["customer_type"]=> string(8) "customer" ["customer_status"]=> string(8) "enquirer" ["marketing_status_id"]=> string(2) "16" ["marketing_optin_date"]=> NULL ["marketing_optin_method_id"]=> NULL ["marketing_contact_method_id"]=> NULL ["marketing_reason_for_leaving_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["address1"]=> string(0) "" ["address2"]=> string(0) "" ["address3"]=> string(0) "" ["telephone"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["website"]=> string(0) "" ["facebook"]=> NULL ["twitter"]=> NULL ["linkedin"]=> NULL ["googleplus"]=> NULL ["pinterest"]=> NULL ["notes"]=> string(0) "" ["number_on_roll"]=> string(0) "" ["form_entry"]=> string(0) "" ["agreement_renewal_date"]=> NULL ["postcode_data_id"]=> NULL ["services_interested_id"]=> NULL ["organisation_deliveries_id"]=> NULL }

Мой инпут с названием "marketing_reason_for_leaving_id" и равен 1,как выяснилось это айди взначения в . Данные в выпадающем списке получаю из таблицы БД.
Контроллер:

```
private function _save()
  {

    $id = (int)$this->input->post('id');

    if(empty($_POST)){ echo'error';}else
    // get original customer status so we can determine whether to update
    // the subscription active date or not
    $original_record = $this->organisation_model->get_by_id($id);

    $marketing_optin_date = $this->input->post('marketing_optin_date') ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $this->input->post('marketing_optin_date')))) : null;
    $agreement_renewal_date = $this->input->post('agreement_renewal_date') ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $this->input->post('agreement_renewal_date')))) : null;

    $postcode_data_id = $this->input->post('postcode_data_id') ? $this->input->post('postcode_data_id') : null;

    $postcode_new = $this->input->post('postcode_new') ? $this->input->post('postcode_new') : null;

    if(isset($postcode_new) && $postcode_new != null && $postcode_new != '') {

      $new_postcode_id = $this->lookup_model->save_postcode_if_not_exist($postcode_new);

      $postcode_data_id = $new_postcode_id ? $new_postcode_id : $postcode_data_id;
    }

    $vars = array(
      'title'                            => $this->input->post('title'),
      'subscribed'                       => (int)$this->input->post('subscribed'),
      'subscribed_active'                => (int)$this->input->post('subscribed_active'),
      'description'                      => $this->input->post('description'),
      'customer_type'                    => $this->input->post('customer_type'),
      'customer_status'                  => $this->input->post('customer_status'),
      'marketing_status_id'              => $this->input->post('marketing_status_id') ? $this->input->post('marketing_status_id') : null,
      'marketing_optin_date'             => $marketing_optin_date,
      'marketing_optin_method_id'        => $this->input->post('marketing_optin_method_id') ? $this->input->post('marketing_optin_method_id') : null,
      'marketing_contact_method_id'      => $this->input->post('marketing_contact_method_id') ? $this->input->post('marketing_contact_method_id') : null,
      'marketing_reason_for_leaving_id'  => $this->input->post('marketing_reason_for_leaving_id') ? $this->input->post('marketing_reason_for_leaving_id') : null,
      'address1'                         => $this->input->post('address1'),
      'address2'                         => $this->input->post('address2'),
      'address3'                         => $this->input->post('address3'),
      'telephone'                        => $this->input->post('telephone'),
      'email'                            => $this->input->post('email'),
      'website'                          => $this->input->post('website'),
      'facebook'                         => $this->input->post('facebook'),
      'twitter'                          => $this->input->post('twitter'),
      'linkedin'                         => $this->input->post('linkedin'),
      'googleplus'                       => $this->input->post('googleplus'),
      'pinterest'                        => $this->input->post('pinterest'),
      'notes'                            => $this->input->post('notes'),    
      'number_on_roll'                 => $this->input->post('number_on_roll'),
      'form_entry'                     => count($this->input->post('form_entry')) > 0 ? $this->input->post('form_entry') : NULL,        
      'agreement_renewal_date'           => $agreement_renewal_date,
      'postcode_data_id'                 => $postcode_data_id,
      'services_interested_id'           => count($this->input->post('marketing_services_interested_in')) > 0 ? $this->text_helper->get_ids($this->input->post('marketing_services_interested_in')) : NULL,
      'organisation_deliveries_id'       => count($this->input->post('organisation_delivery')) > 0 ? $this->text_helper->get_ids($this->input->post('organisation_delivery')) : NULL,
    );

    // marketing emails - when you change the status and also they are subscribed
    // we set the date for CRON and also maybe send some email(s)
    $send_email = false;
    if ($vars['subscribed_active'] && (
        !$this->input->post('subscribed_active_date') ||
        $original_record['customer_status'] != $vars['customer_status']
      ))
    {
      $vars['subscribed_active_date'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      $send_email = true;
    }

    $user = $this->user_model->get_logged_in_user();

    if ($organisation_id = $this->organisation_model->save($vars, $id, $user->id))
    {
      // save stages
      $vars['organisation_current_stages_id'] = '';
      $this->lookup_model->delete_lookup_organisations_stages($organisation_id, 'lookup_organisation_stages');

      $stages = $this->input->post('organisation_stage_ids');

      if ($stages != null && count($stages) > 0)
      foreach ($stages as $key => $value) {
        $args = array();
        $args['organisation_id'] = $organisation_id;
        $args['stage_id'] = $value;
        $args['created_by'] = $this->input->post('ff_organisation_stage_' . $value) ? $this->input->post('ff_organisation_stage_' . $value) : $user->id;
        $args['modified_by'] = $args['created_by'];
        $args['id'] = 0;
        if ($this->lookup_model->save_lookup_organisations_stages($args, 'lookup_organisation_stages')) {
          $vars['organisation_current_stages_id'] .= $value . ' ';
        }
      }

      $this->organisation_model->save($vars, $organisation_id, $user->id);

      $this->session->set_flashdata('notice', '<strong>Success!</strong> Item saved!');
    }
    else {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('error', '<strong>Error!</strong> Item not saved!');
    }

    if ($this->session->userdata('referrer_url')) {
        $redirect_back = $this->session->userdata('referrer_url');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('referrer_url');
        redirect($redirect_back);
    } 
    else {
      redirect('/contacts/organisations');
    }
  }
```

Вьюха:

```
<div id="reason_leaving" class="span2">
      <h5>Reason For Leaving</h5>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="marketing_reason_for_leaving_id" id="reason_for_leaving" class="span12" data-placeholder="- Select One -" autocomplete="off">
          <?php foreach ($lookup_marketing_reason_for_leaving as $r): ?>
            <option value="<?= $r->id ?>"<?= set_select('marketing_reason_for_leaving_id', $r->id,
              ($id ?
                ($rowdata['marketing_reason_for_leaving_id'] == $r->id ? true : false) :
                (strtolower($r->title) == 'active' ? true : false))); ?>>
              <?= $r->title ?>
            </option>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Где же вы тут MVC то нашли.

Comment: я модель не добавлял, т.к. считаю лишним. В моей ситуации играет роль контроллер и вьюха.

Comment: не берите в голову, вопрос был риторическим. Я в вашем вопросе не для того чтоб помочь :)

Comment: как удалить вопрос. Вопрос - решен.